# Javascript + selenium, writing readable tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing tests for my web application with `selenium` `webdriver` for `javascript`. The problem that I'm facing is that because many operations are asynchronous, the indentation goes crazy. For example, for reading a value of an element, I'm using a structure

```
driver.findElement(By.id('my-element')).then(function(elem) {
    elem.getAttribute('innerHTML').then(function(text) {
        // Some operation
        // Read next element with same structure
    });
});
```

As you can see, if I need to read values of multiple elements, the indentation gets very deep quickly. Are there some kind of best practices to avoid this kind of issue? Is using "then" the only way to read values from elements?

Comment: This question is more suitable for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is all about writing readable test then you should have some kind of code quality control tool in your codebase.

I prefer [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/help.html), which helps me to write cleaner code. It follows the standards of *ECMAScript Programming Language* and complains me if find any issues.